# SharePoint 2010 - Workflow design limitations?

Tags: 2010, workflow

I´m searching for the default design limitations from SharePoint 2010 Workflows.

How many Workflows can simultaneously run?

How many Workflow instances can be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the technet resource at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Workflow - it has the limits described in the section i've linked for you.